# Spivak's construction of the cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

I'm having some trouble reproducing Spivak's construction of the cross product (p.83 in his "Calculus on Manifolds").

He restricts it to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and does so by defining for $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, with $\varphi$ defined by
$$\varphi(w)=\det\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\ \vdots\\v_{n-1}\\w\end{pmatrix}$$
then $\varphi\in\Lambda^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  Therefore, there is a unique $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t.
$$\langle w,z\rangle=\varphi(w)=\det\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\ \vdots\\v_{n-1}\\w\end{pmatrix}$$

Now I've given this a go in $\mathbb{R}^3$, using the usual basis for $v$ (i.e. $v_1=e_1$, $v_2=e_2$ etc) and an arbitrary $w$
$$w=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$
so $\varphi(w)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  However, the requirement for $z$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}\cdot z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
which to me seems fulfillable by $z=e_1$ or $z=e_3$, which would not be unique (and since this is the $\mathbb{R}^3$ case we know that only $e_3$ is the correct answer).  What's wrong with my understanding?

Comment: The value of $\langle w,z\rangle$ should agree with the determinant *for all* $w$.

Comment: @user1551 I see, it now also makes sense why he didn't give any specifics about $w$.  Could you write this as an answer so I can mark my question as resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of $\langle w,z\rangle$ should agree with the determinant *for all* $w$. The vector $z$ is unique, for, if we find some vector $z'$ such that $\langle w,z\rangle=\langle w,z'\rangle$ for all $w$, we must have $\langle w,z-z'\rangle=0$ for all $w$. In particular, $\langle z-z',z-z'\rangle=0$ and hence $z-z'=0$.

Since $\varphi$ is a linear form, we have $\varphi(w)=\varphi(\sum_iw_ie_i)=\sum_iw_i\varphi(e_i)$. So, we may explicitly express $z$ as $\big(\varphi(e_1),\varphi(e_2),\ldots,\varphi(e_n)\big)$.